# WebLogic 12.2.1: Override Jackson library in common_modules with version in EAR

Tags: spring, jackson, weblogic12c

Given a Spring 4.3.11-RELEASE web application with Jackson 2.8.10 deployed on WebLogic 12.2.2.1, we're running into issues because the Jackson version being loaded is the old one that is in the WLS `oracle_common/modules` tree, which takes preference over other libraries.

We tried the following:

1. Adding preference statement in weblogic.xml

`<prefer-application-packages>`

`<package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>`

`</prefer-application-packages>`

Running with the `-verbose:class` flag clearly shows that the bad jars are being loaded:

> [Loaded com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.ArrayType from
>   file:/u01/oracle/oracle_common/modules/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind.jar]

2. Putting the com.fasterxml.jackson.* jar files in the domain `lib` folder

Nothing worked.

Also, please note this is a shared WebLogic instance where we only have write access to the domain folder, so we can't do creative ideas like physically removing the offending legacy Jackson jars from the oracle_common folder, or messing with the patch_classpath or similar.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look on [Reverse the CLASSLOADER order (BEA)](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0551.html). A little bit strange that filtering does not work. Properly configured reverse class loader order should do the trick. Classes from app should take precedence over share one.

Comment: @MichałZiober as indicated, already tried the prefer-application-packages but it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: What about `<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>`. `prefer-application-packages` is another solution.

Comment: Actually just found out the issue... we were editing the weblogic.xml inside a WAR inside a EAR... put the prefer-application-packages directive in weblogic-application.xml at the EAR lib level, and now it's working. *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks for rubber ducking :) I think someone might benefit from this in the future anyway, so I would propose to leave it, unless there are strong opinions against.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the `prefer-application-packages` directive was being put in the weblogic.xml inside a WAR package inside the EAR, and the classpath was not picking that in the right order:

`foo-ear -> foo.war -> WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`

We solved it by putting the directive at the EAR level:
`foo-ear -> META-INF -> weblogic-application.xml`

Now it's working correctly.